# How to separate an armature bone from an armature bone in an animation?

Tags: animation, armature

Im doing an animation that uses a hand and a sword. The hand swings the sword alot thats why there is a bone from the hand connected to the sword, but problem is, i want to throw the sword in my animation, but I dont know any way on how to detach the sword from the hand.

Comment: The sword it´s a part of the mesh? Just go into edit mode select the mesh from the sword and press "p" then hit "selection". Now your sword it´s a object a part from the hand, if you have the animation ready it will keep the animation now you just need to animate the sword be throwing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to separate the bones:

• Select the armature;

• Enter Edit Mode;

• Select the bone you want to separate;

• Hit "p";

• Click Separate bones.